# Windows Phone - Call default web browser

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am trying to develop Windows Phone App, I would like to know that how can I call the default web browser with a specific URL(e.g. http://www.google.com) when I launch the program?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with "when I launch the program"? after loading the first page?, lanching webbrowser directly instead of main page? if you want simply to launch the webbrowser use WebBrowserTask class as described here: http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/How-to-Navigate-to-an-external-URL-in-WP7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're launching "the program" as you say (Internet Explorer) you use the following code:

```
WebBrowserTask browser = new WebBrowserTask();
browser.URL = new Uri("http://www.google.com", UriKind.Absolute);
browser.Show();
```

The WebBrowser task is inside the Microsoft.Phone.Tasks namespace, the documentaion of which is here: [Microsoft.Phone.Tasks.WebBrowserTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.webbrowsertask(v=vs.92).aspx)

You should also know that the "default" browser is always Internet Explorer, because right now there is no way for users to define an alternative browser as their "default".

**Edit**:

After reading your question more closely, I can tell there is a little bit of ambiguity. If you want to launch the browser immediately when your app launches, you should know the following:

1. This kind of application will fail Microsoft's marketplace validation (check the [Application Certification Requirements for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh184843(v=vs.92).aspx)
2. Even if it didn't fail the certification, it would be a kind of strange application... not one that is of very much use to your users.

If, however you intend to launch the phone's browser when the user clicks a button, then the above code I posted will work just like you want it to, just make sure to include this line at the top of the code file that it's in:

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: In place of WebBrowserTask.Uri, WebBrowserTask.URL has been made obsolete.

Comment: You are right... Once I'm near a keyboard that isn't a touch screen I'll get an edit in there. Thanks!